# Find common data between groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data

```
DeveloperId   Date             remark
--------------------------------------
1             02/01/2013        Google
1             02/02/2013        MSN
1             02/03/2013        Google
1             02/02/2013        MSN
1             02/01/2013        Yahoo
2             02/01/2013        Google
2             02/02/2013        Yahoo
2             02/03/2013        Google
2             02/01/2013        Google
```

How to find common dates for google and Msn and yahoo dynamically ?

I would like to put such query in a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with temp as
(
    SELECT Date, Remark
    From MyTable
    GROUP BY Date, Remark
)
SELECT Date
FROM temp
GROUP BY Date
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9105

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Query for dates that have all types of remarks
SELECT
  Date
FROM
  data
GROUP BY 
  Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT remark) = (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT remark)
  FROM data
);
```

Or, if that wasn't the requirement...

```
-- Query for dates that have more than one remark.
SELECT
  Date
FROM
  data
GROUP BY 
  Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT remark) > 1;
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/324e8/9)

Answer (score 1):

Common dates for 3 different remarks:

```
SELECT t1.DATE
FROM TABLE T1
INNER JOIN TABLE T2
ON t1.DATE = t2.DATE
AND Remark IN ('google', 'yahoo', 'msn')
GROUP BY t1.DATE, t1.REMARK
HAVING COUNT(t1.DATE) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Date from data
group by remark, Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select "Date"
from myTable
group by "Date"
where remark in ('Google','MSN','Yahoo')
having count(distinct remark) = 3
```